# Google Analytics v4 on Android. Dispatch Frequency

Tags: android, google-analytics

Here is my XML configuration file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:ignore="TypographyDashes">

    <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-XXXXXXXX-YY</string>
    <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>
    <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>

    <screenName name="com.gui.Activity1">Activity1</screenName>
    <screenName name="com.gui.Activity2">Activity2</screenName>
    <screenName name="com.gui.Activity3">Activity3</screenName>

</resources>
```

Here is an initialization of a `GoogleAnalytics` instance in a helper class.

```
private GoogleAnalyticsHelper() {
    mGoogleAnalytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(KMSApplication.sAppContext);
    mTracker = mGoogleAnalytics.newTracker(R.xml.tracker_global_config);
}
```

[The documentation says](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/analytics/GoogleAnalytics.html) the default dispatch period is 30 minutes; however, I can see reports in my GA console both in the Real-Time Overview page and in the Events Overview page in a few minutes. Why?

I'm worried about battery drain which may be caused by frequent dispatches.